# Publishing project that includes SQLite.Interop.dll fails because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sqlite, visual-studio-2013

We've recently added `SQLite` to an existing `C# WebForms` application running on `IIS` and we're now having problems publishing it from `Visual Studio` or `Team City`.

If we try to publish after a user has accessed a route that in turn accesses the `SQLite DB` we get the following error:

> Unable to add 'bin/x86/SQLite.Interop.dll' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'bin\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll'.  The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

In order to minimize the problem scope I carried out the following steps:

1. Created a new `C# Web API project.`
2. Added the `System.Data.SQLite.Core NuGet package.`
3. Added the code shown below.
4. Added a publish profile to publish to the local file system and published it.
5. Ran the following `IISExpress` command `iisexpress /path:c:\path-to-application /port:8081`
6. Navigated to `http://localhost:8081/api/values` in the browser which correctly responds with the rows from the relevant `SQLite table`

If we then try to publish again we receive the error described above, which echoes the problem we see in production under `IIS`.

In order to successfully deploy to the production site we have to stop the `app pool`, publish and then restart the `app pool`.

This is far from ideal. Any thoughts on how we can resolve this issue?

Here's the code ...

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    var dbPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MyDB.sqlite");
    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;", dbPath)))
    {
        var rows = new List<string>();
        conn.Open();
        var sql = "select * from myTable";
        using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    rows.Add(reader["mycolumn"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        return rows;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must stop the web site during deployment. You should had done that *anyway*, irrelevant of the DLL locking, because requests handled during the deployment will yield unpredictable results from mixing old and new code.

Comment: Thanks Remus. Seems obvious when you say it, but historically we've  just used a publish step from Team City w/out stopping the app. We've now amended those steps so we now build a ```package```. Then use ```msdeploy``` with ```recycleMode="StopAppPool"``` to stop the ```App pool```. Then use ```msdeploy``` to deploy the ```package``` and finally use ```msdeploy``` with ```recycleMode="StartAppPool"``` to start it again and all is well.